# Scaling <use>d external SVGs with correct aspect ratio

Tags: css, svg

I want to use an (external) SVG icon and want to be able to style the fill color using CSS (as far as I can see, the best way to do this is creating a `<svg><use xlink:href="…" /></svg>` structure at every place where I want to use it). Simultaneously I want it to be scalable with correct aspect ratio, so it can be used around different text sizes.

But scaling with `height:1.5em;width:auto` AFAICS only works when the SVG has a `viewBox`. Is there a way to obtain that viewBox or do the scaling correctly without it?

Comment: extrnal SVG icons can only be styled by CSS that's within the external icon file itself. You could load the icon file using XMLHttpRequest read the viewBox off using the DOM.

Comment: starte of the art would be to turn your SVG's into an icon font:
You can turn your SVG's into a font using http://fontello.com/ for example...

Comment: @RobertLongson: I am trying to use the structure described in the question in order to get around having to use an XHR because that is a more powerful capability that is therefore more likely to be blocked by an ad/script/request blocker. Otherwise I would have used that.

Comment: If you're not willing to use XHR then best give up as you've painted yourself into a corner from which there's no escape.

Comment: @HolgerWill: for my motivations to use SVG, see http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/27/svg-icons-ftw/ (not my post, but describes my reasons pretty well)

Answer (score 0):

If your SVG editor doesn't add a `viewBox`, there is no easy way to get it - other than working out the dimensions yourself and adding it manually.

- Use your mouse coordinates readout in your editor, or
- Use javascript and call `getBBox()` on an appropriate element, or
- Use trial and error. Fiddle with the x, y, width, and height iteratively until you narrow in on the dimensions.

Comment: To be precise: the external file has a viewBox. My problem is that because the SVG elements are not accessible (AFAIK) through the `<use` DOM node, so I don't know how to automatically set it on the inline `<svg>`.

Comment: I've tried your `getBBox()` suggestion, but I always get an empty SVGRect as a result.

Comment: It seems [SVGUseElement.instanceRoot](http://html5index.org/SVG%20-%20SVGElementInstance.html) does what I need, but at least the Firefox Nightly that I use does not implement it.

Comment: Why do you need to add the viewBox at run time?